# Material UI Typography doesn't work in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used Material UI Typography component in the react app. Although I imported necessary files it doesn't function and also no errors shown. I am unable to find what's happening in my code.

```
import React from "react"; 
import HomePage from "../pages/home/index.jsx"; 

function App() { return ( <HomePage /> ); } 

export default App
```

```
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";
import Greeting from "../../components/home/greeting";

class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
           <Greeting/>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

```
import {Component} from "react";
import React from "react";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

class Greeting extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                        Hello World!
                    </Typography>
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Greeting;
```

Comment: Is it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-rubin-hp815f?file=/src/Greeting.js) ?

Comment: Can you show your App.js file ?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes. But not in my browser

Comment: @unhackit import React from "react";
import HomePage from "../pages/home/index.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <HomePage />
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't function"? What specifically about it is not functioning?